# Why is Date.getMinutes() returning 2 for the time 4:00 PM?

Tags: date, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a customized function that does some calculations for a given time.

When a time is entered in a cell, for example `4:00 PM`, this is automatically converted into a date, in this case `12/30/1899 16:00:00` and when the function `getTheMinutes()` is called, it returns `2` instead of `0`.

```
function getTheMinutes(dateTime){
  return dateTime.getMinutes();
}
```

The behavior of the function is different if it's used for a most recent date like `5/1/2019 16:00:00`.

I want the user to be able to just write a time in a cell then use the customized function in another cell. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Please include enough code in your question to replicate the issue. I had to make some assumptions, but with your code, [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/qy6d9ea4/2/).

Comment: Likely the place you are in had a timezone offset that was different to what you expect. Many places didn't have even hour or half hour offsets before 1900. BTW, parsing of "12/30/1899 16:00:00" is implementation dependent so you might get different results in different hosts.

Comment: @Santi All this is happening in google sheets, so I type `4:00 PM` in cell `A1`, and then I type `=getTheMinutes(A1)` in cell `B1`, and the result I'm getting is `2`. Of course, getting the number of minutes is not all I want to do but just part of if, I know I could use the function `MINUTE()` for that. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Char Also make sure your spreadsheet timezone and script timezone are the same

Comment: If you convert the Date to a String you will be able to see if the TimeZone is messing with your numbers.

Comment: @TheMaster @Jescanellas I think this case is not timezone related, because I get a correct number when I use `datetime.getHours()`

Comment: I can't replicate the issue in my Sheet. For me it returns the correct value no matter what date I use. Can you provide a sheet link example? Does it happen in other sheets too?

Comment: @Jescanellas sure! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1psm8_GJYRczO53TILJCOzo0p4GpnS-ooiGWqOJrC8ZU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jescanellas and yes, it happens in any sheet.

Comment: @Jescanellas and can you share your sheet too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have indicated the time zone for your spreadsheet I can confirm what [@RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) deduced almost a day ago, which is that Guatemala adjusted its difference relative to UTC. Something you have confirmed is treated as by two minutes with effect from October 5, 1918.

More specifically, the adjustment was of 2 minutes and 4 seconds and effective from 03:00 that day:

[image: IANA TZ extract]

(Source [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) Version `2019b` file `northamerica`.)

There have been very many such minor adjustments around the world over the years (even between towns in the same country) and adjustments continue, though usually of a whole hour – between 'standard' and Summer time. Sheets has very properly recognised that "normal arithmetic" 'does not work' across such a transition and while noon yesterday to noon today for example is normally, for any one specific location, a difference of 24 hours it is often 23 hours or 25 hours on the day that clocks go forward/back.

And the moral of the story is to beware of obliging Sheets to assume, for want of a specific date, that is has the index number `0` - i.e. is December 30, 1899.

Comment: Thank your for that helpful research.

Answer (score 0):

I made some testing, and I found out that the formula is giving a wrong result any minute before `10/5/1918 0:03:00`, from that DateTime on, the formula is working as expected.

Here is my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1psm8_GJYRczO53TILJCOzo0p4GpnS-ooiGWqOJrC8ZU/edit?usp=sharing

I would need to do a date validation in my customized formula to make it useful. I don't know why google sheets is choosing that date as default when just a time is typed in a cell, I think it should be improved.